# How to prevent future date with vanilla javascript in input textbox

Tags: javascript

```
 function isValid(date) {
      const year = date.slice(6,10);
      if(year && (year < 1990 || year > 2099)) {
       return false;
      }
     return /^(0?[1-9]|1[012])\/(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/\d{4}$/i.test(date);
}
```

I want to prevent the user from entering the future date, I'm trying to validate the Date of birth of the user.

Eg: 
    06/05/2021 - True 
    07/05/2021 - False 
    09/09/2025 - False 
    05/05/1978 - True

Comment: Parse the date into a `Date` object, then compare it with `new Date()`

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```html
<input type="date" onchange="checkDate(event.target.value)" />
```

JS

```js
function checkDate(value) {
  if (value > new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)) {
    throw new Error("lol")
  } else {
    console.log("Good!") 
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/donald-moore/pen/RwpyMBN